# How to combine two queries as a single result set in SQL for Categories - Subcategories?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ListStockBySubCategory]
(   
    @CategoryID varchar(10),
    @SubCategoryID  varchar(10),
    @startRowIndex  int,
    @maximumRows    int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT ISBN FROM (
SELECT ISBN, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(AddedDate DESC) AS RowNum
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(CategoryCode)) + '%' AS Pattern
        FROM tblSubCategories
        WHERE SubCategoryID = @SubCategoryID) Cats
        JOIN tblStock Stock
        ON Stock.CategoryCode LIKE Cats.Pattern 
) AS Info
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) - 1
)
```

Which thanks to help from others on StackOverflow, would list all the items with a Given SubCategory - however I want to be able to include the following:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(CategoryCode)) + '%' AS Pattern
    FROM tblCategories
    WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID) Cats
    JOIN tblStock Stock
    ON Stock.CategoryCode LIKE Cats.Pattern
```

So that it gets the Categories as a Set, then the SubCategories is a SubSet of this, for example I have a Category of EG, which contains two SubCategories EG-EG and EG-IE which themselves are a List of category codes, for example:

EG-EG
- ETC
- ECT
- TCE
EG-IE
- EIEG
- EGIE

How to I get it so it does the Categories then from this List then does thr SubCategories, as part of this I need a "NOT" behaviour as there will be a General Category which will pick up all the left over SubCategories, that are not specifically stated, but would be picked up by the Category Query.

I just cannot find the right combination for this - SubCategories and Categories work seperately but I want them to be SuperSets and SubSets of each other.

---

Here is the the ListStockByCategoryFunction:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ListStockByCategory]
(   
    @CategoryID varchar(10),
    @startRowIndex  int,
    @maximumRows    int
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
SELECT ISBN FROM (SELECT ISBN, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AddedDate DESC) AS RowNum
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(CategoryCode)) + '%' AS Pattern
        FROM tblCategory
        WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID) Cats
        JOIN tblStock Stock
        ON Stock.CategoryCode LIKE Cats.Pattern
) AS Info
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) - 1
)
```

---

I have a Solution which works, however the performance is not acceptable, could anyone help with this as I have been working on it for some time and cannot seem to find a way to optimise this - the SubCategories are a SubSet of the Categories if this helps, see the example below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ListStockBySubCategory]
(   
    @CategoryID     varchar(10),
    @SubCategoryID  varchar(10),
    @startRowIndex  int,
    @maximumRows    int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (
SELECT ISBN FROM (
SELECT ISBN,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AddedDate DESC) AS RowNum
FROM BooksInStock WHERE ISBN IN
(SELECT ISBN FROM(SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(CategoryCode)) + '%' AS Pattern
        FROM tblCategories
        WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID) Cats
        JOIN tblStock Stock
        ON Stock.CategoryCode LIKE Cats.Pattern
WHERE 
ISBN IN
(SELECT ISBN FROM(SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(CategoryCode)) + '%' AS Pattern
        FROM tblSubCategories
        WHERE SubCategoryID = @SubCategoryID) Cats
        JOIN tblStock Stock
        ON Stock.CategoryCode LIKE Cats.Pattern))
) AS Info WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) - 1)
```

Comment: how does the first result set map/join/relate to the second result set?  without a clear answer to this, I doubt that anyone can answer correctly

Comment: I'm not sure I was very clear here - I will add the other function in full if this helps.

Comment: I have added the solution I have so far and a bounty so a more effiencient method can be found - I have tried INTERSECT and EXCEPT but this increases Reads by 10x. I need a least-reads solution for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far - will have to wait a couple of days for me to try them, but will mark an answer then!

Comment: I don't see your Create Table & Create Index statements, nor sample data.  If you want good performance, you need to give us something that we can test performance against.

Comment: Oh, and I do not see anywhere that you show us exactly *what* query you are executing against this function when you are measuring its performance.  That is *VERY* important for a TVF.

Comment: Questions: 1) Typically how many CategoryCodes are there in a CategoryID?  2) Why are you using LTRIM on CategoryCode?  That causes a lot of performance problems for a "paging" query like this.  What are the values of @startRowIndex and @maximumRows that you are using for performance tests? 4) How slow is it now, and how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: And is BooksInStock a Table or a View?  Because it looks like View, and if so, we need to see its definition.

Comment: I'm guessing more information was required, this was an intial "is there anything I can do" however I have found an alternative solution. But the view I have when correctly indexed does improve the performancr of my existing function - and some of the variations here and ones I have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, its impossible to say without the table definitions, keys, indexes query plans or data examples, but I think that this will help some:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ListStockBySubCategory]
(   
    @CategoryID     varchar(10),
    @SubCategoryID  varchar(10),
    @startRowIndex  int,
    @maximumRows    int
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT ISBN FROM 
    (
        SELECT  ISBN,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AddedDate DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM BooksInStock 
        WHERE EXISTS
        (        
            SELECT *

            FROM tblStock AS stk
            JOIN tblStock AS stk2         ON stk.ISBN = stk2.ISBN
            JOIN tblCategories AS cat     ON cat.CategoryID = @CategoryId
            JOIN tblSubCategories AS sub  ON cat.CategoryID = sub.CategoryID

            WHERE cat.CategoryID = @CategoryId
              AND sub.CategoryID = @CategoryId
              AND bis.ISBN = stk.ISBN
              AND  stk.CategoryCode LIKE RTRIM(LTRIM(cat.CategoryCode))+'%'
              AND stk2.CategoryCode LIKE RTRIM(LTRIM(sub.CategoryCode))+'%'
        )
    ) AS Info 
    WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) - 1
)
```

Comment: Yes I'm guessing more information would have helped, thanks for the example anyway, all these solutions have given me alternatives to try, which is very helpful.

Comment: This solution uses joins in a way I had not considered, although I have an alternative I'm awarding this as the answer as it would be the way I would have wanted to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Utlimately, if I'm following the requirements right (and without table schemas and knowledge of the data contained, it's pretty convoluted), the inner subquery that you have aliased as "Info" will need to contain two UNION ALLed queries--the "new" one on tblCategories and the "old" one on tblSubCategories.

The tricky part will be working out ordering, particularly since your current sorting criteria (AddedDate) appears to have nothing to do with your desired sorting criteria (Category and SubCategory). Work that out, and based on that perhaps add some columns that will be used only for ordering.

Comment: I think you may be correct, the UNION of the tblCategories and the tblSubCategories is what I want - I just cannot get it to work, without SQL errors.

Comment: Are you having problems writing the Union, applying the row_number to that subquery, or filtering/ordering the result? (I'd recommend working on those problems in that order -- build the inner query, then "exapnd" it out.)

Comment: This is still an issue as I cannot figure out how to get these two lists to work together of subcategories and categories.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the core SELECT:

```
SELECT ISBN FROM tblStock a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tblCategories b
    WHERE b.CategoryID = @CategoryID
      AND a.CategoryCode LIKE RTRIM(LTRIM(b.CategoryCode))+'%'
    )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tblSubCategories b
    WHERE b.SubCategoryID = @SubCategoryID
      AND a.CategoryCode LIKE RTRIM(LTRIM(b.CategoryCode))+'%'
    )
```

That gets rid of two DISTINCTs.

Beyond that, you still have an expensive-looking query that would probably benefit from better indexing.

If you provided the DDL statements for tblStock, tblCategories, tblSubCategories, and BooksInStock (including all indexes and key constraints), I could provide some recommendations there.